# PHP MySQL API Can't Drop Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to drop a table with php. I have been working with php for a couple of months now, and don't see why I am getting an error. Sample Code:

```
include 'SQLaccount.php';
$sql = "DROP TABLE RequestBooks;";
if (!$accountCon->query("SET a=1")) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n <br> SQL: %s", $accountCon->error , $sql);
}
$accountCon->close();
```

And this is the error:

```
Errormessage: Unknown system variable 'a' //What I get when I run theabove code
SQL: DROP TABLE RequestBooks;
```

I can drop the table from PHPMyAdmin, and the user I am using has all permissions granted. I use this same query setup for all of my mysql needs, with no problem.

Edit 1:

I was running a query on SET a=1 and not $sql.

```
include 'SQLaccount.php';
$sql = "DROP TABLE RequestBooks;";
if (!$accountCon->query(**$sql**)) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n <br> SQL: %s", $accountCon->error , $sql);
}
$accountCon->close();
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: We will assume you meant ->query($sql) ... nothing to see here

Comment: If you are really trying to drop the table, shouldn't `if (!$accountCon->query("SET a=1"))` be `if (!$accountCon->query($sql))`??

Comment: `a` is undeclared, perchance?

Comment: @hd1 I don't even see how `a` is related here.

Comment: He's getting the error because a is undeclared...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
include 'SQLaccount.php';
$sql = "DROP TABLE RequestBooks;";
if (!$accountCon->query($sql)) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n <br> SQL: %s", $accountCon->error, $sql);
}
$accountCon->close();
```

Comment: Thanks man. I don't know how I missed that when I was going through it.